# Helper Not Detcteing Subfolder Paths Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

On my helper function if controller is in parent directory I can load controllers from subfolders

```
load_controller('subfolder/class');
```

**Problem**

If I have a controller that is in a subfolder and want to use this

`load_controller('subfolder/class');`

I cannot pick it up other controllers if I call them from a controller that is in a sub directory

**How can I make it so it will pick up controller which ever controllers and controller subfolder I am in.**

Helper

```
<?php

function load_controller($controller, $method = 'index', $params = '') {

    // From Parent Folder "Controllers"

    require_once (APPPATH . 'controllers/' . $controller . '.php');

    $controllername = basename($controller);

    $controllername = new $controllername();

    return $controllername->$method($params);
}
```

Comment: Name of operating directory can be used and/or compared to with magic constant `__DIR__`. [Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your load_controller is as follows:

```
load_controller($controller, $method , $params){}
```

It only accepts 3 variables, but you are trying to send location information ('subfolder/class'), which you are not accounting for in your controller.

In order to fix it you need to add another paramater like this:

```
function load_controller($location, $controller, $method , $params){
     require_once (APPPATH .$location. 'controllers/' . $controller . '.php'); //and apply it to the path
}
```

Comment: Is there away with out adding another variable?

Comment: Not really. you could pass an array with all the parameters you need, but you still need to pass some type of variable, whether its inside an array or not, in order to set the path.